# C++ Dice Program Difficulties

Tags: c++, loops, random

Question:

> Repeatedly roll 3 dice until doubles are rolled (any two are the
>   same).  Show the values each time and afterwards state how many tries
>   it took to get doubles.

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    srand (time(NULL));
    int j=1;
    int i=0;
    int a;
    int b;

    do
    {
        int a=(rand ()%6+1);
        int b=(rand ()%6+1);

        cout<<a<<" and "<<b<<endl<<endl;
        j++;
    }
    while (a!=b);

    cout<<"They are the same!"<<endl<<endl;
    cout<<"It took "<<j<<" tries.";

    return 0;
}
```

Problem:

The loop doesn't stop. Even when a and b are the same the program doesn't stop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are redefining `a` and `b` inside your `do ... while` loop. Remove the `int` before the second `a` and `b` definitions, where you assign the random values to the variables, and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

You're declaring new variables inside the loop that shadow the a and b that you declared outside of the loop. `while (a != b)` is looking at the outside ones, but you're not changing those.

Get rid of the `int` on `int a = (rand() % 6) + 1`

If you're using gcc/g++, you could probably save yourself some pain with the `-Wshadow` flag to your compiler. For other compilers, I don't know what the option is, but there probably is one. At least that'd tell you the problem at compile time instead of run time.